# What are the differences between Pale Ale (PA), India Pale Ale (IPA) and American Pale Ale (APA)?

Tags: brewing, specialty-beers, craft-beers, hops

I am wondering because I want to brew these styles of beer myself.

Comment: You can get excellent descriptions of those and many other styles at Beer Advocate: https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/

Comment: Another great place to understand different styles is https://www.bjcp.org/docs/2015_Guidelines_Beer.pdf and you should be asking these beer questions on the homebrew stack exchange because those guys are the real beer geeks.

Comment: Might be a better fit on homebrew.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, pale ale is not as hoppy as India pale ale. So, quantity of hops in and IBU of IPA’s will be generally higher compared to pale ales. American pale ales use American hops instead of traditionally popular European hops.